# How to read pptx engine name from pptx files

Tags: powerpoint, openxml

Given pptx file, how to know which engine created the file? (Ex, MSOffice, docx4j/pptx4j, etc.) Perhaps, there is some place in Office Open XML structure where it's acceptable to put the signature.

Answer (score 0):

It would normally go in the extended properties part:

```
<Properties xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/extended-properties">    
  <Application>Microsoft Office PowerPoint</Application>
```

which Powerpoint stores at /docProps/app.xml

That part can also contain <AppVersion>

No guarantee that an application will write or update that though.  docx4j, for example, will do so only if configured to.